# How do I emit an event into gulp-tap's parent stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, node-streams

I'm setting up a gulpfile for bundling multiple JavaScript files into multiple bundles during development.

Since I want to watch this process and not have it exit if there is an error (syntax or something) in one of the files I would need to properly emit an `end` event to the parent stream.

For handling the multiple files I am using the [approach described in the gulp recipes](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/90340b9e64c1e88debc2238fda14b25a4270fb49/docs/recipes/browserify-multiple-destination.md).

But using this and reading the [docs on gulp-tap](https://github.com/geejs/gulp-tap) I am unsure how to have it emit the error into the parent stream.

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
gulp.task('bundle', () => (
    gulp.src(['whatevs/*.js'], { read: false })
        .pipe($.tap((file) => {
            file.contents = browserify( // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
                file.path,
                { debug: true, fullPaths: true }
            ).bundle();
        }))
        .on('error', function handleBrowserifyError(err) {
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('bundles/'))
));
```

I can see the error if I would pass a callback to the `bundle()` call, but I do not have the slightest clue how to get it back into the parent stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
gulp.task('bundle', () => {
    const scriptStream = gulp.src(['whatevs/*.js'], { read: false })
        .pipe($.tap((file) => {
            file.contents = browserify( // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
                file.path,
                { debug: true, fullPaths: true }
            )
            .bundle()
            .on('error', () => scriptStream.emit('end'));
        }))
        .on('error', Function.prototype) // prevents crashing
        .pipe(gulp.dest('bundles/'));
    return scriptStream
});
```